# What does Remove-AzureVM do?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Specifically, when does it return?  Does it return when the VM has been completely deallocated and all resources released (if I used the -deleteVHD option)?  Or does it return when the process of deleting the VM and disks has been started?

I'm working on a script that removes a VM, and I need to know if I have to loop and check the VM status before returning success.  In every instance but one, the VM has been gone after Remove-AzureVM returned and I don't know if this is expected or a bug.

Comment: It's worth noting that Remove-AzureVM removes the allocated resources, _excluding_ any VHD files -- those you'll have to remove separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Remove-AzureVM does complete the operation before it returns the status.

For your requirement, you could do the below.

```
$Status = Remove-Azurevm -Name <vm-name> -ServiceName <service-name>
if ($Status)
{
  if ($Status.OperationStatus -eq "Succeeded")
  {
    Write-Verbose " VM Deleted successfully"
    <Your logic on what to do next>
  }
}
else
< Your logic on what to do >
```

Hope this helps!